# Read Line Having Track Revisions in Word

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is there any way I can find Line Having Track Changes [Inserted or Deleted] using Open XML SDK. I have tried with below code I am able to detect whether document body having Track Changes or Not and It Works correctly Now What I want is to find which Text line of body contains track changes

```
 public static System.Type[] trackedRevisionsElements = new System.Type[] {
    typeof(CellDeletion),
    typeof(CellInsertion),
    typeof(CellMerge),
    typeof(CustomXmlDelRangeEnd),
    typeof(CustomXmlDelRangeStart),
    typeof(CustomXmlInsRangeEnd),
    typeof(CustomXmlInsRangeStart),
    typeof(Deleted),
    typeof(DeletedFieldCode),
    typeof(DeletedMathControl),
    typeof(DeletedRun),
    typeof(DeletedText),
    typeof(Inserted),
    typeof(InsertedMathControl),
    typeof(InsertedMathControl),
    typeof(InsertedRun),
    typeof(MoveFrom),
    typeof(MoveFromRangeEnd),
    typeof(MoveFromRangeStart),
    typeof(MoveTo),
    typeof(MoveToRangeEnd),
    typeof(MoveToRangeStart),
    typeof(MoveToRun),
    typeof(NumberingChange),
    typeof(ParagraphMarkRunPropertiesChange),
    typeof(ParagraphPropertiesChange),
    typeof(RunPropertiesChange),
    typeof(SectionPropertiesChange),
    typeof(TableCellPropertiesChange),
    typeof(TableGridChange),
    typeof(TablePropertiesChange),
    typeof(TablePropertyExceptionsChange),
    typeof(TableRowPropertiesChange),
};

    public static  bool PartHasTrackedRevisions(OpenXmlPart part)
    {
        List<OpenXmlElement> insertions =
         part.RootElement.Descendants<Inserted>()
        .Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList();
        //Body bdy = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        if (part.RootElement.Descendants()
            .Any(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e.GetType())))
        {
            var initialTextDescendants = part.RootElement.Descendants<Text>();
            string dummy = string.Empty;
            foreach (Text t in initialTextDescendants)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(t.Text);
            }
        }
        return part.RootElement.Descendants()
            .Any(e => trackedRevisionsElements.Contains(e.GetType()));
    }

    public static bool HasTrackedRevisions(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        if (PartHasTrackedRevisions(doc.MainDocumentPart))
            return true;
        foreach (var part in doc.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
            if (PartHasTrackedRevisions(part))
                return true;
        foreach (var part in doc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts)
            if (PartHasTrackedRevisions(part))
                return true;
        if (doc.MainDocumentPart.EndnotesPart != null)
            if (PartHasTrackedRevisions(doc.MainDocumentPart.EndnotesPart))
                return true;
        if (doc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart != null)
            if (PartHasTrackedRevisions(doc.MainDocumentPart.FootnotesPart))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var documentName in Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.docx"))
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentName, false))
            {
                if (HasTrackedRevisions(wordDoc)) {
                    //Body bdy = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                    //var initialTextDescendants = bdy.Descendants<Text>();
                    //string dummy = string.Empty;
                    //foreach (Text t in initialTextDescendants)
                    //{
                    //    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + t.Text;
                    //}


                    Console.WriteLine("{0} contains tracked revisions", documentName);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain tracked revisions", documentName);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, @John were you able to get the paragraph of the line for track changed?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "Text line of body"? The line of text as it would appear on a laid out document (which is not easy) or the Open XML elements that were changed?

If this is about the line of text on a laid out document, as produced by Microsoft Word, this is hard, because you would require a layout algorithm to understand where the lines with those tracked changes would be rendered.

If this is about the OpenXmlElements, e.g., Text or Paragraph, you already have part of your solution as this is about querying the XML mark-up.